# Time precision between NTP and GPS source

Tags: time, gps, ntp, gps-time

I have NTP client implementation (on Linux) to send/receive packets to (Stratum 1 or 2) NTP server and get the server time on the board. Also, I have another application running on Linux which gives me the GPS time. 
Before I get the time information from NTP and GPS source, I will be setting the time manually(using date) on the board close to current GPS time(this info is taken from http://leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm).

Keeping the system time on the board as the reference, I will take the difference of this reference time with NTP(say X) and GPS(Y). The difference between X and Y is coming to be 500+ ms. I was curious to know the time precision between NTP and GPS.
Is 500 ms an expected value?

I tried enabling hardware time-stamping on the NTP client,however it has not made any difference.

Comment: Two questions before I give you my answer: 

Is your GPS connected via USB? Why dont you set up your ntpd to use the gps as a time source?

Comment: The setup is not in my place where I am working.I shall check it and let you know if it is connected via USB. Any specific reason you asking me this question? And, The reason for not using gps is, if we are keeping the board in a remote location where there is no connectivity, then it will be a problem.

Comment: GPS over USB is really jittery. If there is no connectivity how are you going to use ntpd?

Comment: I mean to say, no GPS connectivity or GPS signal strength is low, in that case, I need to use NTP server.

Answer (score 3):

Using a GPS as a reference clock boils down to one thing: PPS (Pulse-Per-Second). Everything else is pretty jittery (unstable/unpredictable).

The PPS output is extremely accurate (nanoseconds).

PPS does not contain any information except when a second starts. That means we have to feed our clock the date and time from another source. NMEA (the actual data from the GPS) is fine as long as it’s good enough to determine the time to one second accuracy.

My guess is that your “GPS time” is the time (and date) from the GPS “data outlet”. This time can be off by 500ms (or even worse) and that’s normal. That’s why we do not use that time as an accurate reference clock.

Comment: Also the PPS signal has to be connected via a low-latency method, such as an RS232 control line or interrupt-triggering GPIO pin.  If it's connected via a USB-to-RS232 cable, the USB protocol will add a lot of latency to the PPS signal.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to read about time references. I think the GPS time system is not strictly identical to the UTC time returned by those time-server. The time measured by the atomic clocks have a leap second added periodically to get UTC time within +/1 second of the astronomical time which is not stable.

Is your NTP implementation able to correct network latency ? Try using a NTP server with a low-latency to you...

These factors may explain the difference you see.

Comment: Thanks Simon.But i think, network latency will not be the cause for the difference. While calculating the time on the server,taking into account of network latency.

Comment: GPS does not use astronomical time but TAI too. The offset to UTC is broadcast, so that doesn't explain the difference. As @JeffMerlin explained, the NMEA data stream is not accurately timed, which does.

Comment: `Is your NTP implementation able to correct network latency ?` Weird question considering that latency compensation is a core part of NTP protocol... Also, the presence or absence of leap seconds cannot account for _fractional_ differences such as the 0.5 s reported by OP.